# How to optimise/parallelise solr's grouping

Tags: solr

I'm trying to use ["results grouping"](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html) functionality for the sake of optimisation:
instead of making N requests to the solr and asking for products (docs) in specific category (special field in each doc) I want to make single request and retrieve all at once.

#### Examples:

1.

```
GET /select?fq=category:foo&rows=5

[{ean1}, {ean2}]

GET /select?fq=category:bar&rows=5

[{ean3}]
```

2.

```
GET /select?group=true&group.query=category:foo&group.query=category:bar&group.limit=5

{
 foo: [{ean1}, {ean2}],
 bar: [{ean3}],
}
```

My guess was that second solution will be faster, but it's not (for the user): in first example I make async calls and I receive results from both request almost at the same time. So while in the first example Solr do more work, it does so in parallel and as the result users see responses faster.

Any suggestion about how to optimise grouping?

(For the context: we are using Solr 5.5.5)

Comment: As in documentation "Prefer Collapse & Expand instead.
Solr’s Collapse and Expand feature is newer and mostly overlaps with Result Grouping. There are features unique to both, and they have different performance characteristics. That said, in most cases Collapse and Expand is preferable to Result Grouping."

Comment: That said, 5.5 is pretty old but Result collapsing does exist

Comment: But again, your query is as slow as your slowest group. Not sure why that would be a performance optimizer in the first place.